# Limit the number of appends in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wan't to limit the number of append that happen in Jquery whenever I click the button

```
    function standardRoom() {
  var flag = 0
  if ($('select#selectBoxStandard option').length > 1 ) {
    flag++
    $('#selectBoxStandard').find("option:nth-last-child(-n+" + $('#selectBoxStandard').val() + ")").remove();
    if (flag <= 1) {
        $("#roomDetail ul").append('<li><strong>Standard Room - Regular Online Rate</strong> </li>').append('<li class="pull-right"><h4 style="color:darkorange">PHP {{$availableRooms[0]['nightRate']}}</h4></li>').append('<li>Number of night(s): {{$n_nights}} </li>').append('<li>Number of person(s): </li>').append('<li class="hr">Number of room(s): </li>').append(flag);
    }
  }else {
    alert("No more rooms");
  }
}
```

I tried using if statement based on what I find here. But it's not working, it just keeps on appending.

Comment: Your `flag` variable is reset to zero every time the function is called.

Comment: You define a variable as 0, add 1 to it, and then check if it equals 1.  Hint: It always will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you call standardRoom function the `flag` variable is reset to 0, so it will always keeps adding the elements. Make sure you store that variable somewhere more global where you don't need to reset it:

```
   var flag = 0;
   function standardRoom() {
       if ($('select#selectBoxStandard option').length > 1 ) {
           flag++
           $('#selectBoxStandard').find("option:nth-last-child(-n+" + 
           $('#selectBoxStandard').val() + ")").remove();
           if (flag <= 1) {
               $("#roomDetail ul").append('<li><strong>Standard Room - Regular Online Rate</strong> </li>').append('<li class="pull-right"><h4 style="color:darkorange">PHP {{$availableRooms[0]['nightRate']}}</h4></li>').append('<li>Number of night(s): {{$n_nights}} </li>').append('<li>Number of person(s): </li>').append('<li class="hr">Number of room(s): </li>').append(flag);
           }
       } else {
          alert("No more rooms");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Yes...I see my bad

Answer (score 1):

`flag` gets reset on every function call. Define it outside the function.

```
 var flag = 0    
    function standardRoom() {

          if ($('select#selectBoxStandard option').length > 1 ) {
        flag++
        $('#selectBoxStandard').find("option:nth-last-child(-n+" + $('#selectBoxStandard').val() + ")").remove();
        if (flag <= 1) {
            $("#roomDetail ul").append('<li><strong>Standard Room - Regular Online Rate</strong> </li>').append('<li class="pull-right"><h4 style="color:darkorange">PHP {{$availableRooms[0]['nightRate']}}</h4></li>').append('<li>Number of night(s): {{$n_nights}} </li>').append('<li>Number of person(s): </li>').append('<li class="hr">Number of room(s): </li>').append(flag);
        }
      }else {
        alert("No more rooms");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) instead of your  local variable. 
At dom ready you can set the value of flag data attribute for your selectBoxStandard element and after you can use it:

```js
// init flag value
$('#selectBoxStandard').data('flag', 0);

function standardRoom() {
    // get flag value
    var flag = $('#selectBoxStandard').data('flag');


    if ($('select#selectBoxStandard option').length > 1 ) {

        // update flag value
        $('#selectBoxStandard').data('flag', flag++)

        $('#selectBoxStandard').find("option:nth-last-child(-n+" + $('#selectBoxStandard').val() + ")").remove();
        if (flag <= 1) {
            $("#roomDetail ul").append('<li><strong>Standard Room - Regular Online Rate</strong> </li>').append('<li class="pull-right"><h4 style="color:darkorange">PHP {{$availableRooms[0]['nightRate']}}</h4></li>').append('<li>Number of night(s): {{$n_nights}} </li>').append('<li>Number of person(s): </li>').append('<li class="hr">Number of room(s): </li>').append(flag);
        }
    }else {
        alert("No more rooms");
    }
}
```